# Add alternate user to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: amazon-ec2, users

I have installed PHPMyAdmin on my EC2 instance, and I just wanted to know how I could add a separate user with the same privileges as the root user to the program.

I am running a LAMP stack with Apache2.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loggin to PHPMyAdmin with a mysql user, so, if you create a user in mysql
create user `'username'@'host' identified by 'somepassword'` you will be able to access to phpmyadmin and check all the databases you have permissions on it, you can give privileges using `grant all privileges to *.* 'username'@'host' with grant option;` it should work